# Customize "Continue Shopping" Button - Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am pretty new to Woocommerce and i've just added a "Continue Shopping" button to my cart and product pages.
This is the code i use now, that goes directly to the shop page:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_coupon', 'continue_shopping_button', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', 'continue_shopping_button', 10 );

function continue_shopping_button(){
  ?>
    <a class="button wc-backward" href="<?php echo esc_url( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_return_to_shop_redirect', wc_get_page_permalink( 'shop' ) ) ); ?>">
    <?php _e( 'Continue shopping', 'woocommerce' ) ?>
    </a>
  <?php
}
```

Instead of this, I would like the button to take the guest to the shop page after applying his last searched parameters, if he has used any. So, let's say a customer searched for a product by name or by category, viewed it and (maybe) added it to the cart. I want him, at any one of those step, to be able to return to the shop page and see the same products he was viewing before, without having to search for them again.
Sorry, if this has already been answered but i haven't found any code that solves this for woocommerce.
I assume it's doable with cookies, but i can't figure it out. Any help will be appreciated and thank you all in advance.

Comment: So what is working and what not… what is your question here as it's not clear… Please **"edit"** your question to clarify. Thanks.

Comment: You should really try googling before posting in here. https://gist.github.com/bradleysa/7d1448253097784daf94

Comment: @LoicTheAztec sorry if i wasn't very clear. I've edited it - hope it makes more sense now. Thanks.

Comment: @Nikos Gkogkopoulos i have seen this post. My issue is with maintaining each guest's last search results and using them as parameters when they click the "Continue Shopping" button to go to the shop page again.

Comment: This is really too complicated and I am not sure that is doable in a simple way (so your question seems too broad for stackOverFlow as it's). You should need to rethink better that, to search more, to make some more tries and go more forward, before asking.

Comment: @Bambinos like really, it's the second query in google :P   https://wordpress.org/plugins/continue-shopping-for-woocommerce/

If this doesn't work, you should try rethinking about your implementation. Perhaps a custom redirect based on cookies or whatnot

Answer (score 0):

If you did not find the solution in our comments, you could also try this:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_coupon', 'continue_shopping_button', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', 'continue_shopping_button', 10 );

function continue_shopping_button(){
  ?>
    <a class="button wc-backward" href="<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ?>">
    <?php _e( 'Continue shopping', 'woocommerce' ) ?>
    </a>
  <?php
}
```

which creates a link on the button to redirect the user to the page that linked to this page. It is a simple "go back in history by 1 page", so keep in mind that if you go to cart after x pages after selecting a product, clicking on this will get you to x-1 page, not the starting product one.

The plugin i suggested in the comments though, seems to be doing a pretty good work!

Comment: Yeah, seen it before. It's close but it doesn't work for the cart page, since it isn't one step away. Still, thanks for your time, man. I appreciate it. I'm currently trying to make tit work with cookies.